# problem with sql left join

Tags: sql

i build 3 table

```
tb1 for book
tb2 for sub subject
tb3 for main subject
```

each book have 1 sub subject and each sub subject have 1 main subject
i want make join between book=> sub subject => main subject

i make join between book and sub subject but cant make between sub subject with main subject

```
select book.id, book.titl, subsubject.title, mainsubject.title
from book
left join subsubject on book.id = subsubject.book_id
```

i want complete this statement to add main subject

Answer (score 1):

Wow, I think I understand...
You want something like:

`SELECT book.id, book.titl, subsubject.title, mainsubject.title FROM book,subsubject,mainsubject
WHERE book.id = subsubject.book_id AND
subsubject.book_id=mainsubject.book_id`

You could replce the `WHERE` with;

`LEFT JOIN subsubject on book.id = subsubject.book_id
LEFT JOIN mainsubject on book.id = mainsubject.book_id`

Also,do you mean book.title?

(My SQL may not be perfect, but *should* work)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select book.id, book.titl, subsubject.title, mainsubject.title
from book
left join subsubject on book.id = subsubject.book_id
left join mainsubject on subsubject.book_id=mainsubject.book_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is probably that you need a different join condition between sub and main than between book and sub:

```
select *
from book join sub on book.id = sub.book_id
    join main on sub.sub_id = main.sub_id
```

I'm not sure why a left (=outer) join would be required if each book must have one subject and each subject needs a main.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select b.id, b.title, s.title, m.title
from book b
left join subsubject s
  on s.id = b.ss_id
left join mainsubject m
  on m.id = b.m_id
where b.id = (id of book you'd like)
```

Hope this helps.